# Preserving 3Ds Max Smoothing Groups - Importing a model from 3Ds Max to Blender

Tags: import, geometry, subdivision-surface, conversion, smooth

I'm trying to work out how feasible it will be to move a model created in 3Ds Max to Blender to test/compare some plugins only available in Blender.

Unfortunately, this model uses a lot of smoothing groups. These smoothing groups don't seem to translate well to blender. When applying the subdivision modifier it seems to ignore (or not find) any smoothing groups that were present in 3Ds Max, even though the Smoothing Groups option is ticked in the .FBX export settings.

Is there a way of preserving the smoothing groups that appear in 3Ds Max? A plugin, way of saving/importing, or something that can help the Blender model to match the 3Ds Max model?

Comment: Have you tried Checking "Subdivision Data" on the FBX import dialog?

Comment: That does seem to add a Subdivision Surface modifier, but it still doesn't look anything like how it does in 3Ds Max.